# Create a struct with a blank address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I have the following defined struct:

```
// A struct that holds all the data for a single plot of land
    struct Land {
        bytes32 geoPoint1;
        bytes32 geoPoint2;
        bytes32 geoPoint3;
        bytes32 geoPoint4;
        address owner;
    }
```

and I call it using the following

```
Land memory _land = Land({
                geoPoint1: _geoPoint1,
                geoPoint2: _geoPoint2,
                geoPoint3: _geoPoint3,
                geoPoint4: _geoPoint4
                owner: ?????
            });

            uint256 landID = landRegister.push(_land) - 1;
```

What do I put into the owner field because I want to leave that as "empty" i.e.

> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

When someone purchases this item the field will be completed. If I leave it blank I get errors in Remix stating that there are not the expected number of fields for the struct.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you *don't* want to use 0 for some reason? I would personally just use 0.

Comment: No, I am pretty new to this and wasn't sure how to set a blank address. If it is as simple as using 0 then thats great.  Is it just a simple case of checking for 0 when I want to determine if empty? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This should work:

```
Land memory _land = Land({
                geoPoint1: 1,
                geoPoint2: 2,
                geoPoint3: 3,
                geoPoint4: 4,
                owner: address(0)
    });
```